# How to force 1 table column to be the same width as another column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table with several columns that are getting dynamically populated with data. I'd like column 3 to be any width it wants, and I want to force column 4 to have the same width as column 3. Is this possible?

Comment: Share your html and css please. And what do you mean 'any width it wants'? Do you want the table to take up the whole screen or to take as little space as possible? Be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You need JS to solve this with an Event Listener to start the script assoon as the page is loaded: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ ... });`

You can get the width of an element by using: `document.querySelector('.row-3').offsetWidth;`

then you set the width of another element by using: `...style.width = ...`

The issue is, that `offsetWidth` get the width of an element incl. padding and border. As such we have to set the `<tr>`in css to: `box-sizing: border-box;`. Then the width will include paddings and border aswell. Another issue is, the `offsetWith` will get a rounded width value to full pixels. So there is a light difference of up to 0.5px due to the roundings.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  let rowWidth = document.querySelector('.row-3').offsetWidth;
  document.querySelector('.row-4').style.width = rowWidth + "px";
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td class="row-3">A3 extra wide</td>
    <td class="row-4">A4</td>
    <td>A5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>B5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>C5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```